# Is it possible to change the ocean levels after blowing up a continental land bridge?

Tags: internal-consistency, geography, earth-like, map-making

I am somewhat new to worldbuilding so forgive me if I am not as clear as I could be.

I have created a continent, but for relate-ability sake, imagine the US and Mexico, but where the Yucatan Peninsula peters off into Costa Rica, instead it widens back out into another large landmass. Looking at the Mexican map, right about where Coatzacoalcos is, and directly across the shortest point, the people of the northern side of that line plan to blow that land bridge to prevent the southerners from continuing to invade their country. (obviously with other security precautions in place to prevent attacks from the sea)

My original thought with this was that in blowing the land bridge, if the water levels change to become lower after that, it will reveal a lost island off the eastern shore of the northern land mass. Is this even possible? Or am I barking up the tree of fantastically far-fetched?

So I added my rough draft map. The area of land to be blown to smitherines will be in the middle of Serraud, the blue line between the two 'R's marks the line of detention. the small unmarked group of islands to the east in the ocean marked "Leeron" would be the so-called lost islands to be discovered if the water levels change.

[image: 1]]

Comment: Nice map! Are the Leeron Ocean and the western ocean connected in the south (or north), as with the Drake passage in the North America and South America situation?

Comment: Initially my thoughts are yes, the oceans are connected through a passage far in the south similar to the Drake Passage. The northern continent continues on past the northern pole and down the other side of the planet past the equator. But due to the lost island component in my story, the continent shapes and attachments to other continents is flexible in order to come up with the result I would like

Answer (score 10):

**It could change level, but not significantly.**

Going from your example of Central America, we can look at the sea level differences for the Pacific and Atlantic oceans across the Panama Canal. It's about [20 cm higher on the Pacific side](http://www.psmsl.org/train_and_info/faqs/). For the non-metric folks, that around 8 inches.

Of course, if the difference in seal level was on par with what we see on Earth for your planet, there wouldn't be much to uncover in the Leeron Ocean. In fact, more would be uncovered during normal wave motion. Also note that even after the oceans equalized you'd get an average of the difference, not the complete difference.

However, if you made Leeron into an inland sea, you're much more likely to be able to tweak things to get the desired effect. Take the [Caspian Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspian_Sea) for example, it's Earth's largest inland sea. It's surface level is 28 meters (98 feet) below sea level. That's pretty significantly different than 20 centimeters! If the area gets enough rainfall and has fairly clay heavy soil, there isn't any particularly compelling reason the Leeron Sea couldn't be 25 or 100 meters above sea level. So when the land bridge is blown is could empty into the western ocean and expose the islands as planned.